# How to stop finally block from execute in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a try block.Inside that try block again `try` block and it's `finally` block.I closed that outside try block.followed by `finally` block.Suppose I don't want to execute the `finally` block,for that I wrote `Environment.Exit(0)`.Does there is any other method that stop finally block from `execution.return 0;`(that is in java).Please let me know.

```
public static int Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First try block");

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Second try block");
                    //exit(0);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    //return 0;
                }

                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Finally block of inner try");
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finally block of second try");
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I closed that outside try block"?  Please post some code.

Comment: how many ways can one (mis)spell block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Environment.FailFast() to exit the application immediately, while skipping finally and finalizers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx

Comment: Environment.FailFast() is another method that stop finally block from being execute.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx) -

> The statements of a finally block are executed when control leaves a try statement, whether the transfer of control occurs as a result of normal execution, of execution of a break, continue, goto, or return statement, or of propagation of an exception out of the try statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use one try block and few catch blocks. If one type of exception require some action you can enter them into that block and leave finally block empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - the `finally` block is *always* executed, unless for some reason the JVM exits before it gets to it.    [Link from MSDN](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

I'm not quite sure why you would want to do this, anyway. Sounds like you may need to change your design somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Use a boolean to determine which code in your `finally` block is called.

```
    public static int Main()
    {
        bool complete = false;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First try block");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Second try block");
                //exit(0);
                //Environment.Exit(0);
                return 0;
            }

            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finally block of inner try");
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            if (complete)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finally block of second try");
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure to set your `complete` variable somewhere.

Answer (score -3):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int a = 10/0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Statement 1");
                break;
                Console.WriteLine("Statement 2");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```